# facebook get all public photos by searchterm

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, photos

I write a cronjob, the cronjob fetches the data from facebook and displays.
I used to fetch the data https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=query&type=posts
I got all public posts, but I only get photos which are shared.

How can I get all photos in facebook by a given searchterm.

Comment: Photos is not an object that's query-able via the graph api. The list of supported objects are listed here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Hi, is there any otherway, maybe over fql?